# Here Maps Android SDK PositioningManager start method returns false

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using Here Maps on my Nexus 6P to test out their navigation routing logic. I've got the map setup and I'm currently trying to get my location to show up on the map.

Here maps v3.2.1 Premium Version running on Android 6.0.1

But every time I call the start method for PositioningManager instance I get a false return. Here is my code :

```
mapEngine.init(context, new OnEngineInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) {
            if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {

                setupMapView(mapView);

                // Start the positioning manager
                positioningManager = PositioningManager.getInstance();
                positioningManager.addListener(new WeakReference<PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener>(positionListener));

                if(positioningManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK_INDOOR)){
                    Log.d(TAG, "LOCATION STARTED SUCCESSFUL");
                }else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "LOCATION STARTED UNSUCCESSFUL");
                }

                map.getPositionIndicator().setVisible(true);

                listener.onMapEngineCompleted(error);
            } else {
                // handle factory initialization failure
                Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                Log.e(TAG, error.getDetails());
                Log.e(TAG, error.getStackTrace());
                listener.onMapEngineCompleted(error);
            }
        }
    });
```

I've also already got ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission granted from the system

Comment: Did you request or need the indoor positioning functionality ? Since its access is restricted in 3.2.1, please try starting the positioning without INDOOR.

Comment: @Marco I'ved tried that and no luck. Here is my permissions list :         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

Comment: Please add another service, next to the map service to your manifest: <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.here.services.internal.LocationService" android:process=":remote"></service>
Please let me know if this fixes your issue.

Comment: @Marco Thanks Marc, that was it!

Answer (score 2):

As I ran into the same problem, I will put the answer from @Marco's comment here. If the `positioningManager.start()` method is returning false you may have to include this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.here.services.internal.LocationService" android:process=":remote"/>
```

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Hi there - I tried this but it doesn't help. I think I must have some other issue, although this compiles, in Androis Studio the line
android:name="com.here.services.internal.LocationService" is in red from "sevices" onwards