# Using HERE positioning without Wifi or SIM

Tags: android, here-api

I have set up a simple app to get position from HERE (with some help graciously given by HERE Developer Support) that question is [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54327538/240795)

This code works fine on my phone to produce a GeoPosition once per minute in my log.

I am now trying to run this code on my target tablet. The tablet is old (runs Android 5.1), does not have GPS and does not have a SIM or an phone connectivity. The only possible location method is to use Wifi. I have tested the HERE test app on the tablet and it found a good approximate location based on Wifi connections - this is what I am trying to duplicate.

When I try to initialize the PositionManager with LocationMethod of GPS, or GPS_NETWORK or NETWORK I get the same error

for these lines:

```
    PositioningManager pm = PositioningManager.getInstance();
    PositioningManager.LocationStatus  ls = pm.getLocationStatus(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS);
    Log.i("Position", "Setting up positioning");
    if (ls ==  PositioningManager.LocationStatus.AVAILABLE) {
        Log.i("Position", "Positioning is available");
    } else {
        Log.w("Position", "Positioning not available right now: " + ls.toString());
    }
    boolean ret = pm.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS);
    Log.i("Position", "Positioning start returns " + ret);
```

I get these logs:

```
01-27 06:00:21.656 16636-16636/? I/Position: Setting up positioning
01-27 06:00:21.657 16636-16636/? W/Position: Positioning not available right now: OUT_OF_SERVICE
01-27 06:00:21.660 16636-16636/? W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider doesn't exist: network
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1550)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:582)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:899)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:500)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at com.here.android.mpa.internal.v.a(DeviceLocation.java:117)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at com.here.android.mpa.internal.ea.a(PositioningManagerImpl.java:224)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at com.here.android.mpa.common.PositioningManager.start(PositioningManager.java:153)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at com.company.app.MainActivity.setUpPositioning(MainActivity.java:63)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at com.company.app.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:137)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at com.company.app.MainActivity.checkPermissions(MainActivity.java:108)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at com.company.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
01-27 06:00:21.661 16636-16636/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
01-27 06:00:21.666 16636-16636/? I/Position: Positioning start returns true
```

and every minute I check the position

```
            GeoPosition pos = PositioningManager.getInstance().getPosition();
```

and it is null. If I set the LocationMethod to NULL i don't get an exception, but I still don't get any GeoPosition.

how do HERE manage it in their test app, to get a position from Wifi alone?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Test app being referred is the one available in github (https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/positioning) , the recommendation would be to use the LocationDataSourceHERE and use the GPS_NETWORK_INDOOR mode for starting positioning.

```
mHereLocation = LocationDataSourceHERE.getInstance( new StatusListener() {
// implement the callbacks 
..
});
mPositioningManager.setDataSource(mHereLocation);
..
// start position updates, accepting GPS, network or indoor positions
if (mPositioningManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK_INDOOR)) {
     // positioning started sucessfully
} else {
      T// error                        
}
```

There might be some special permissions required if you also want to use the indoor positioning feature using indoor radio map ([documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/advanced-positioning.html))